# Json extract coming as null - Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I`m trying to use json extract to get some values using the code below:

```
json_extract_scalar(properties,'$.partner_target_app_id') as partner_target_app_id,
```

And it works, however the values are coming all as NULL . When I extract the properties field I get the values that I want, as the example below:
{"allow_url":false,"partner_target_app_id":[28479748204829001,9388018374784],"link":"http"}

Does anybody know what could be the issue here? I thought it was something related to the [] around the numbers but I also tried to use '$.[partner_target_app_id]') and also got the same result.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`json_extract_scalar`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html?highlight=json_extract_scalar#json_extract_scalar) is for extracting scalar values (numbers, strings, booleans). In your example, the value associated with `partner_target_app_id` is an array.

You can use [`json_extract`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html?highlight=json_extract#json_extract), which, in this case, returns a value of type `JSON` containing a JSON array of numbers, and cast it to SQL array:

```sql
SELECT cast(json_extract(x, '$.partner_target_app_id') as array(bigint)) 
FROM (
    VALUES '{"allow_url":false,"partner_target_app_id":[28479748204829001,9388018374784],"link":"http"}') t(x);
```

```
               _col0
------------------------------------
 [28479748204829001, 9388018374784]
(1 row)
```